# Angular does not load images correctly on server with nginx

Tags: css, angular, nginx

So i have 3 different angular projects, ***pj1, pj2*** and ***pj3*** which i'm trying to deploy using nginx. The aim is to have the routes as follows:

```
  www.mysite.com/     ---> loads the pj1
  www.mysite.com/pj2  ---> loads the pj2
  www.mysite.com/pj3  ---> loads the pj3
```

### Folder structure

The folder structure looks like this:

- my-projects

  - pj1
  - pj2
  - pj3

### Nginx configuration

My nginx configuration file looks like this:

```
server {
root /usr/share/nginx/my-projects;

location /pj1/ {
    autoindex on;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /pj1/index.html;
}

location /pj2/ {
    autoindex on;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /pj2/index.html;
}

location /pj3/ {
    autoindex on;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /pj3/index.html;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri$args /pj1/index.html;
}
```

}

### Angular build config

I am building each project with the following command:

```
ng build --prod --aot=true --buildOptimizer=true --base-href /pj1/ --deploy-url /pj1/
```

This is for building the pj1 project as an example, the other ones follow the same pattern.

### The problem: Angular images

The images which are in the html are like this, for example:

```
 <img src="assets/img1.jpg" />
```

It loads correctly, both on server and locally.
However, the images which are referenced in the scss files only load whether on server or locally, depending on how i define their paths.
This path, for example, works perfectly on my local machine, but does not work on the server:

```
background-image: url(/assets/img1.svg);
```

And when i change to the following path, i get an error on the cli saying that it could not load the resource:

```
background-image: url(assets/img1.svg);
```

Though it works if i put it manually with the inspector of the broswer when running on the server. So it works on the server, but not locally.

I don't know exactly what is causing this problem, perhaps angular is not referencing the correct root since it only goes wrong when i put the "/" at the beginning of the path, however if i don't put this there then it does not work on my local machine. Is there  any solution to this? Something that functions both on local machine and server?

Comment: Can you check your base-href on index.html

Comment: Yes, it seems correct, each project has its specified path there, for project one there is "/pj1/", for project two "/pj2/" and so on...

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!
The problem happens due to a weird way that angular handles the paths to images in the css files, as mentioned in [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42802431/angular-2-load-css-background-image-from-assets-folder/65799235#65799235)

So what worked for me was to let the paths as absolutes, like the following example:

```
background-image: url(/assets/img1.svg);
```

And add the following code to my **angular.json** file:

```
"build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
       ...
       "rebaseRootRelativeCssUrls": true
```

This makes angular change the root of where the folder assets is going to be searched, so instead of searching for the images of my project one on **[www.mysite.com/assets/](http://www.mysite.com/assets/)**, for example, it will instead search on **[www.mysite.com/pj1/assets/](http://www.mysite.com/pj1/assets/)** which is in fact just what i needed.